# Cannot declare a class already in use

Tags: php, symfony-3.4

I tried to install and configure SonataUserBundle on my project. I installed and configured correctly SonataAdminBundle and all works fine. But after extends the bundle and generate the application I have errors.
I'm using Symfony 3.4 version.

```
php app/console sonata:easy-extends:generate SonataUserBundle -d src
```

a folder is created on my src folder named Application with the generated app.
I added that too to my bundles.php file :

```
Sonata\UserBundle\SonataUserBundle::class => ['all' => true],
Application\Sonata\UserBundle\ApplicationSonataUserBundle::class => ['all' => true],
```

And configured my routes, but when I run my website, I got this error :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "ApplicationSonataUserBundle" from namespace "Application\Sonata\UserBundle".
```

Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace? in C:\wamp64\www\staff-ma\src\Kernel.php:33

My ApplicationSonataUserBundle class :

```
namespace Application\Sonata\UserBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class ApplicationSonataUserBundle extends Bundle
{
   /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
   public function getParent()
   {
      return 'SonataUserBundle';
   }
}
```

My composer.json :

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "src/"
    }
```

I added that :

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "src/"
        "Application\\": "src/Application/Sonata/UserBundle/"
    }
},
```

But I got another the same error.

Comment: and if you remove `"Application\\": "src/Application/Sonata/UserBundle/"` ?

Comment: same error like before.

Comment: I think you should change this line to `"Application\\": "src/Application"` as the folder Application was added to src

Comment: Changing this line, I have another error : `Fatal error: Cannot declare class Application\Sonata\UserBundle\ApplicationSonataUserBundle, because the name is already in use in C:\wamp64\www\staff-ma\src\Application\Sonata\UserBundle\App"
licationSonataUserBundle.php on line 24`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve the problem. I just added App on my namespace :

```
namespace App\Application\Sonata\UserBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

/**
 * This file has been generated by the SonataEasyExtendsBundle.
 *
 * @link https://sonata-project.org/easy-extends
 *
 * References:
 * @link http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/bundles.html
 */
class ApplicationSonataUserBundle extends Bundle
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'SonataUserBundle';
    }
}
```

And in bundles.php too :

```
return [
    App\Application\Sonata\UserBundle\ApplicationSonataUserBundle::class => ['all' => true],
];
```